# Meteor blaze components event bubbling

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

When I was using Ember.js event bubbling, when a component sends actions and events to its parent, was very useful. I still can't find such feature in blaze components. I thought of passing the event function references down, like:

```
{{> SubComponent args event1=func}}
```

and in definition:

```
// ParentComponent.js
class ParentComponent extends BlazeComponent {
    func(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

// SubComponent.js
class SubComponent extends BlazeComponent {
    constructor(keyword) {
        this.event1 = keyword.hash.event1;
    }
}
```

but it keeps saying that `event1` is undefined. It is present as a key, but contains an undefined value